# Replacing/deleting from one character to another JS

Tags: javascript

I'm currently writing a program that needs to delete/replace with "" from one character to another, heres an example:

`<p id="p1">Hey! I'm a good string<a href="blah">except im here!</a> I wish that <a> tag was gone! </p>`

How would I use JavaScript to delete everything from `<a` to `</a>`? I have a bunch of way I could solve this, but they are uselessly complicated. Any advice on an easy way to do this?

*BONUS POINTS:* Any idea what to do for when I would want the `<a>` tags gone, but the text inside it ("except im here") to remain? Same issue. I could solve it, but it would be overly complicated.

Comment: Use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: What is the point of manually manipulating HTML like this?  There are many implementations of HTML parsers or sanitizers, and trying to do this manually is fraught with land mines.  As it stands now, this *feels like* an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be to use regex, if you already have the text;

```
string.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '');
```

So in your case, lets say you get the string with innerHTML;

```
var p1 = document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML;    
var yourDesiredFormat = p1.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '');
```

As comment from @Saiansh Singh suggests, you can also use the native `textContent` property of a DOM object;

```
var p1 = document.getElementById("p1").textContent;
```

Both of these would give you;

> Hey! I'm a good stringexcept im here! I wish that  tag was gone!

For your input.